# How can I use CONCAT with results from GROUP_CONCAT in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I have trouble with a SPARQL query. I have two graphs: Discipline and Professor. The graph Discipline contains different disciplines and is linked with the Professor thanks to his id. For example, I have:

```
<http://www.rdcproject.com/graph/disciplines> {
    <http://www.rdfproject.com/77803>
        a       <http://www.rdfproject.com/Discipline> ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/cfu>
                "6" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/disciplineAbbreviation>
                "SE" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/disciplinename>
                "Software Engineering" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/hasCourseof>
                <http://www.rdfproject.com/8028> ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/idDiscipline>
                "77803" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/isTaughtBy>
                <http://www.rdfproject.com/0009004> , 
                <http://www.rdfproject.com/0004003> ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/obligatory>
                "false" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/semester>
                "1" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/totalhours>
                "50" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/weekhours>
                "5" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/year>
                "1" .
}
```

This course is taught by two professors:

```
<http://www.rdfproject.com/0009004>
        a       <http://www.rdfproject.com/Teacher> ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/firstName>
                "Koby" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/idProfessor>
                "0009004" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/lastName>
                "Bryant" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/role>
                "contratto" .

<http://www.rdfproject.com/0004003>
        a       <http://www.rdfproject.com/Teacher> ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/firstName>
                "Lebron" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/idProfessor>
                "0004003" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/lastName>
                "James" ;
        <http://www.rdfproject.com/role>
                "associato" .
```

Now I want all professors for all disciplines. I have created this query:

```
PREFIX uni: <http://www.rdfproject.com/>
PREFIX un: <http://www.w3.org/2007/ont/unit#>

SELECT  ?idDiscipline ?disciplineName  
        (CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(?idProf;separator=","),', ',GROUP_CONCAT(?firstName;separator=","),', ',GROUP_CONCAT(?lastName;separator=","),', ',GROUP_CONCAT(?role;separator=","),']') as ?professors)
        
FROM <http://www.rdcproject.com/graph/disciplines>
FROM <http://www.rdcproject.com/graph/professor>
WHERE
{ 
    {
    ?x  a uni:Discipline;
    uni:disciplinename ?disciplineName;
    uni:idDiscipline ?idDiscipline;
    uni:disciplineAbbreviation ?sigleDiscipline;
    uni:cfu ?cfu;
    uni:hasCourseof ?hasCourseof;
    uni:obligatory ?obligatory;
    uni:semester ?semester;
    uni:totalhours ?totalhours;
    uni:weekhours ?weekhours;
    uni:year ?year;
    uni:isTaughtBy ?isTaughtBy.
    ?isTaughtBy a uni:Teacher;
        uni:idProfessor ?idProf;
        uni:firstName ?firstName;
        uni:role ?role;
        uni:lastName ?lastName.
    }
}
GROUP BY ?idDiscipline ?disciplineName
```

This query works fine if a discipline contains only one professor, but in this case the result is:

```
ID -> 77803"  
NAME -> "Software Engineering" 
PROFESSOR -> "[0009004,0004003, Kobe,Lebron, Bryant ,James, 
        contract,contract]"
```

How can I get this result?

```
ID -> 77803"  
NAME -> "Software Engineering" 
PROFESSOR -> "[0009004, Kobe, Bryant, contract] 
              [0004003, Lebron,James, contract]
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @AKSW
My new Query is:

```
PREFIX uni: <http://www.rdfproject.com/>
PREFIX un: <http://www.w3.org/2007/ont/unit#>

SELECT  ?idDiscipline ?sigleDiscipline ?disciplineName ?cfu ?hasCourseof ?obligatory ?semester ?totalhours ?weekhours ?year 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?prof_str;separator=",") AS ?Professor)

FROM <http://www.rdcproject.com/graph/disciplines>
FROM <http://www.rdcproject.com/graph/professor>
WHERE
{ 
    {       
    ?x  a uni:Discipline;
    uni:disciplinename ?disciplineName;
    uni:idDiscipline ?idDiscipline;
    uni:disciplineAbbreviation ?sigleDiscipline;
    uni:cfu ?cfu;
    uni:hasCourseof ?hasCourseof;
    uni:obligatory ?obligatory;
    uni:semester ?semester;
    uni:totalhours ?totalhours;
    uni:weekhours ?weekhours;
    uni:year ?year;
    uni:isTaughtBy ?isTaughtBy.
        ?isTaughtBy a uni:Teacher;
        uni:idProfessor ?idProf;
        uni:firstName ?firstName;
        uni:lastName ?lastName;
        uni:role ?role.
        
    }

    BIND(CONCAT('[',?idProf,',',?firstName,',',?lastName,',',?role,']') AS ?prof_str)

}
GROUP BY ?idDiscipline ?sigleDiscipline ?disciplineName ?cfu ?hasCourseof ?obligatory ?semester ?totalhours ?weekhours ?year
```

Comment: One way to achieve that is to use `CONCAT` within the body of the query and `BIND` it to some variable. Then use `GROUP_CONCAT` over that variable in the projection of the query.

Comment: Can you give me an Example please ?

Comment: build a string for each professor in the query body with e.g. `WHERE { ... BIND(  ($HERE_THE_CONCAT_YOU_NEED) AS ?prof_str) ...}` and use `?prof_str` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Oh Goood! It work ! Thanks